# User input being cut off

Tags: java, validation, input

I have a textfield where a user can enter values.

In its listener, I store the new value to a variable. If that variable is a number, I then proceed to print that number. Example:

```
String val="";
textfield.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov,
                String old_val, String new_val) {

                    val=new_val;

                    if(val.matches("\\d+")) {
                        System.out.println(val); 
                    }
            }
}
```

The problem is when I try to enter a number with multiple digits. If I try `10` it will cut it off at `1` because `1` is the first digit I entered, which triggered the `if`.

After I print the value, it gets sent off to the rest of the program and user input is no longer required. But how is the user supposed to enter two digit numbers? I've tried sleeping the thread but it sleeps everything. I've tried adding filters for numbers `<10` so that they will wait for a possible second digit, but I can't get it to wait. It is always getting cut off at the first digit.

Any suggestions to try?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String val="";
textfield.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov,
                String old_val,
                String new_val) {

                    val=new_val;

                    if(val.matches("\\d+"){1,2}) {
                        System.out.println(val); 
                    }
            }
}
```

It now needs 1 or 2 digits to be a valid match.

Comment: A problem still occurs because I still need the single digit input, not just the double digit.

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement can't be met by simply modifying the listener.

In my past project, I did `submitButton.setEnabled(isValidInput(val))`

And `frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(submitButton)` so that user can submit with the Enter key.

Note: [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) may be a better way of validating user input.